# Extract data from HTML tag

Tags: php, html, extract

I have the following code and trying to extract the value of attribute content from an html page, But it's not giving any result that I expect, instead its give only blank page.

Any help where could be the issue ?

```html
$url= "https://fr-ca.wordpress.org";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
  # Create a DOM parser object
   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadHTML($html);
   foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $key ) {
   echo "<pre>";
   $tab[] = $key->getAttribute('content');
   }
   $reg= '<meta name="generator" content="(.*?)"/>';
   if (preg_match_all($reg, $html, $ar)) {
    print_r($ar);
   }
```

Page source has :

```
<meta name="generator" content="WP 4.5"/>
```

Comment: I think you want to print $ar not $tab. I believe the preg_match arguments are regex, source, results.

Comment: Shouldn't use regex for `HTML` scraping

Comment: @DarkBee Not sure if its too off topic, but can you recommend the best general method to use for HTML scraping?

Comment: Just use the dom parser like in your example code?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$html = '<meta name="generator" content="WP 4.5"/>';
preg_match_all('/content="(.*)"/i', $html, $matches);
if (isset($matches[1])) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Hi @smoqadam, Thanks for the answer, Actually the situation is different because each website will have different output as example above:
 If I print match I have sit index $match[1][4], But if I change the URL I will need to print different index $match[1][x].

How to solve this issue.

Comment: maybe it's better using `php-simple-html-dom-parser` or http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will look for a meta tag and get the content attribute contents. It has some wild cards that will account for other variables such as different names, or extra spaces, etc.

```
$html = '<meta name="generator" content="WP 4.5"/>';

preg_match_all( '#<meta.*?content=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]\s*/>#i', $tab, $results );
print_r( $results[1] ); // contains array of captures.
if( $results[1] ) {
    // code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

preg_match_all( '#<meta name="generator" .*?content="(.*?)"\s*/>#i', $html, $results );

Answer (score 0):

please use like this ...

```
$html = file_get_contents( $url);

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML( $html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

    // A name attribute on a <div>???
    $nodes = $xpath->query( '//div[@name="changeable_text"]')->item( 0);

    echo $nodes->Content;
```

OR

// Use Curl ...

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}
$html=getHTML("http://www.website.com",10);
// Find all images on webpage
foreach($html->find("img") as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links on webpage
foreach($html->find("a") as $element)
echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: And also please check this URL :- https://www.phpclasses.org/package/4433-PHP-Extract-data-between-two-HTML-tags.html#view_files/files/22300